# Is there a way to detect that emacs is running in a terminal?

Tags: terminal-emacs

When I run emacs in a terminal (using the `-nw` option) my theme is broken and some key-bindings don't work.

So, I need to disable the theme and some keybindings when running in a tty.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`display-graphic-p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html) to determine if you are running in a terminal or a windowing system.

For example, you could do your setup so that you only add those keybindings and theme if you know you're on a window system.

```el
(when (display-graphic-p) 
    ;; Do any keybindings and theme setup here
  )
```

You can also do the reverse, and turn off your keybindings and theme.

```el
(unless (display-graphic-p) 
    ;; Remove any keybindings and theme setup here
  )
```

Comment: Matches the suggestion at the bottom of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html

Comment: Do not use window-system and initial-window-system as predicates or boolean flag variables, if you want to write code that works differently on text terminals and graphic displays. That is because window-system is not a good indicator of Emacs capabilities on a given display type. Instead, use display-graphic-p or any of the other display-*-p predicates described in Display Feature Testing.
from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html