# Different theme for -nw (terminal)

Tags: themes, terminal-emacs

I am running emacs (24.5.1) on Mac osx and using the solarized theme. For the gui version, the theme works well. If I run the application with the -nw flag:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw
```

the colors for the theme get all wonky. I assume this is because:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

What would I need to put in my .emacs to give the following conditional behavior:

```
if (gui)
  theme=solarized
if (-nw)
  theme=wheatgrass
```

??

Comment: I was tempted to tell you to write something like: (if (window-system) ...) Then, I read the documentation: > window-system is a variable defined in `C source code'. > Its value is nil It is a terminal-local variable; global value is the
> same.
> > Documentation: Name of window system through which the selected frame
> is displayed. The value is a symbol: > - nil for a termcap frame (a
> character-only terminal), > - 'x' for an Emacs frame that is really an X
> window, > - 'w32' for an Emacs frame that is a window on MS-Windows
> display, > - 'ns' for an Emacs frame on a GNUstep or Macintosh

Comment: If you only need to know how to check if emacs is running in a gui or terminal then I believe this is a duplicate or this: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/is-there-a-way-to-detect-that-emacs-is-running-in-a-terminal  If you also need to know how to enable themes from elisp then I think it stands as it's own question nicely. If you need to know how to programmatically enable themes from elisp I would add that specifically to the body of your question.

Comment: There are themes out there that look nice in both graphical and non-graphical environments. A alternative solution would be to use one such theme.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `display-graphic-p` to determine if Emacs is in a GUI or not.

Assuming solarized is installed and loaded:

```lisp
(if (display-graphic-p) 
    (enable-theme 'solarized) 
  (enable-theme 'wheatgrass))
```

See also: [Is there a way to detect that emacs is running in a terminal?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/is-there-a-way-to-detect-that-emacs-is-running-in-a-terminal)