# How to prevent emacs theme to load when running on terminal

Tags: themes, terminal-emacs

Hi I'm asking this question because this;[1]: [Different theme for -nw (terminal)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13050/different-theme-for-nw-terminal) and few others didn't work for me. Allright, first of all I am not a programmer/devoloper, and I don't know lisp (thinking about learning it, but too busy). The problem I encountered is when I use emacs on gui with standart theme, it hurts my eyes, and the theme is just ugly. But when I use it on terminal (emacs -nw with no theme) it is beautiful because of the terminal theme/compton etc. Sometimes I have to use gui for a quick edit on desktop files or some other files, I'd like to ask you, how can I achive, to run emacs with some theme when on gui, and no theme on terminal.[2]: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html I've seen this part of gnu/emacs manual, I understood what the "display-graphic-p" and "if" codes do but not sure how to use it,  because I don't want any other theme to load on emacs when I use it on terminal.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the following?

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (enable-theme 'solarized))
```

You can replace `'solarized` with another theme.

---

p.s. This `when` expression is equivalent to an `if` with a "do nothing" *else* clause:

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (enable-theme 'solarized)
  nil)
```

Emacs Lisp also lets you write a "one armed `if`":

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (enable-theme 'solarized))
```

But some people (like me) think it's clearer to use `when` -- to
emphasize that the expression is "for effect" not "for result".

Comment: Thank you for the explenation of codes, I really appreciate it. I couldn't make it work though. I managed to load the theme by inserting custom enabled themes "wombat" or "zenburn" but now, the theme loads on terminal too, can not prevent this.

Comment: you should then have something like: `(if (not (display-graphic-p)) (load-theme 'desired-theme t))` in order to load the right theme on terminal

Comment: @mclear Note that `(if (not <cond>) <then>)` is equivalent to `(unless <cond> <then>)`.