# Can't change emacs console/terminal theme (emacs -nw)

Tags: terminal-emacs

I'm using base16-theme package to load my GUI theme and it works fine. However my console theme is completely random (launched with `emacs -nw`).

It doesn't match (not even close) with the GUI theme and frankly I'm not sure what theme it is. Pic [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBMwB.png) shows the console theme and pic [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcZH9.png) the GUI theme.

[image: terminal theme]

[image: GUI theme]
Except custom-safe-themes there's nothing in my custome-set-variable that might interfere with themes settings. Things I've tried so far:

- adding this line to my .zshrc file `export TERM=xterm-256color` -> no effect
- adding conditional statement that should load theme if not in terminal (from [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/is-there-a-way-to-detect-that-emacs-is-running-in-a-terminal) and [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemes#h5o-10))

```
(unless (display-graphic-p)                                                  
    (load-theme 'base16-monokai t))
```

and

```
(unless (window-system)                                                      
  (load-theme 'base16-monokai t))
```

I've also tried `load-theme` and `customize-theme` from terminal buffer it also didn't work. My .emacs configuration for my GUI theme is this:

```
(use-package base16-theme
  :ensure t
  :config
  (load-theme 'base16-monokai t))
```

What could be the problem???

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem. A few things were involved: first off, the if condition was compiled after the theme configuration for GUI, therefore wasn't taken into consideration. I fixed by including both GUI and console theme in the same conditional statement:

```
(if (window-system)
    (load-theme 'base16-monokai t)
  (load-theme 'tango-dark t))
```

Apart from this (which solved most of the problems) I disabled line numbers modeand soft line highlighting because they messed up the colous in terminal mode.

```
;; Enable line numbers globally
(if (window-system)
    (global-linum-mode t)
  (global-linum-mode 0))

;; softly highlight the current line
(if (window-system)
    (global-hl-line-mode 1)
  (global-hl-line-mode 0))
```